# The provided start does not map to a value

Tags: titan, gremlin

I have a traversal as follows:

```
g.V().hasLabel("demoUser")
.as("demoUser","socialProfile","followCount","requestCount")
.select("demoUser","socialProfile","followCount","postCount")
.by(__.valueMap())
.by(__.out("socialProfileOf").valueMap())
.by(__.in("followRequest").hasId(currentUserId).count())
.by(__.outE("postAuthorOf").count())
```

I'm trying to select a user vertex, their linked social profile vertex, and some other counts. The issue is that all users may not have a `socialProfile` edge. When this is the case the traversal fails with the following error:

> The provided start does not map to a value: v[8280]->[TitanVertexStep(OUT,[socialProfileOf],vertex), PropertyMapStep(value)]

I did find [this thread](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TINKERPOP-793) from the gremlin team. I tried wrapping the logic inside of `.by()` with a `coalesce()`, and also appending a `.fold()` to the end of the statement with no luck.

How do I make that selection optional? I want to select a `socialProfile` if one exists, but always select the `demoUser`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`coalesce` is the right choice. Let's assume that persons in the modern graph have either one or no project associated with them:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel("person").as("user","project").
           select("user","project").by("name").by(coalesce(out("created").values("name"),
                                                           constant("N/A")))
==>{user=marko, project=lop}
==>{user=vadas, project=N/A}
==>{user=josh, project=ripple}
==>{user=peter, project=lop}
```

Another way would be to completely exclude it from the result:

```
g.V().hasLabel("person").as("user","project").choose(out("created"),
    select("user","project").by("name").by(out("created").values("name")),
    select("user").by("name"))
```

But obviously this will only look good if each branch returns a map / selects more than 1 thing, otherwise you're going to have mixed result types.